# ReactJS show modal after delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show a Bootstrap modal after delay, however only home page is shown. Please see my code below (no error is detected).

*App.js:*

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

function MyVerticallyCenteredModal() {
    return (
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Modal heading
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
          <p>
            Some Text
          </p>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
}

function App() {

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeId = setTimeout(() => setModalShow(true), 3000)
    
        return () => clearTimeout(timeId)
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Home />
            {modalShow && (<MyVerticallyCenteredModal />)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I think you have some design issue. Try to change MyVerticallyCenteredModal component to simple "div" element and check if that "div" appears after 3 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the timeout logic is the problem here, because even if the conditional `modalShow` is removed, the component still doesn't render.

Try `<Modal.Dialog>` instead of just `<Modal>` for the bootstrap component

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/